# Displaying a secondary custom menu and assign it from admin

Tags: wordpress

I am building a website for a client. 
In the theme I am working with, I need to have a secondary menu specific to each page.

The menus are built in Appearance->Menus but I am now stuck in how to assign and display them in my pages. I need to be able to select the menu in admin for each page.

What would be the best approach for this?

Here is a screenshot of the page currently in development: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend You will Try this

> http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b84z49af2

and Place this code where you want to display menu.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'footer menu'
 ) ); ?>
```